# Clarification on a specific permutation of column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, determinant

The exact steps can be found in the page 31 of Michael Taylor's [Linear Algebra](https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/linalg.pdf). Let $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$ be two permutations of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then with what operations/rules of permutations does one justify the following?

$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))a_{\sigma(1)\tau(1)}\dots a_{\sigma(n)\tau(n)} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma))a_{\sigma\tau^{-1}(1)1}\dots a_{\sigma\tau^{-1}(n)n}$$

I'm asking this because I've seen essentially the same proof in at least four sources, none of which have specified the what and how of the intermediary steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the pair
$$
(\sigma(\tau^{-1}(j)),j).
$$
Since $\tau$ is a permutation, there is some $k$ such that $\tau(k)=j$, in which case $k=\tau^{-1}(j)$. Then, we can see that
$$
(\sigma(k),\tau(k)) = (\sigma(\tau^{-1}(j)),\tau(\tau^{-1}(j)))
=(\sigma(\tau^{-1}(j)),j).
$$
Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are permutations and hence both invertible, this must be the *only* such pair that is equal to the original one. Hence, every pair $(\sigma(k),\tau(k))$ is realized as some pair $(\sigma(\tau^{-1}(j)),j)$, and that guarantees that the two products of $a$'s are identical.

Comment: I see. I suppose the author (Taylor) could also have specified a separation between the subscript indices, meaning that $\sigma(1),\tau(1) \to \sigma\tau^{-1}(1), 1$ instead of $\sigma(1)\tau(1) \to \sigma\tau^{-1}(1)1$, where the latter seems like a three element product. In any case, thanks for the clarification.